# Use DDNS (noip.com) with ngrok

Tags: http, networking, tcp, ngrok, noip

My ISP uses CGNAT so I cannot use portforwarding to access my server. I am using ngrok as a tunnel but everytime I restart, the address changes. So I thought of using no-ip domain as a persistent address and updating it whenever I restart ngrok. But when I use the DDNS domain it gives me a "tunnel not found" error.

[image]

[image]

In the ngrok documentation, there is something about whitelisting domains which requires premium but I dont understand how ngrok can know I am accessing from another domain when the DNS is resolved in the DNS server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTTP request contains the hostname and it is checked by ngrok server application.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use TLS tunnel insted that will bypass ngrok ssl cert